# Relation between number of components in vectors and the dimension of their span.

Tags: linear-algebra

We have $n$ vectors each with $k$ components. Let $V$ be their span and $r$ be the dimension of $V$. Then $r \leq k$.

I encountered this in a paper I am reading. I am not able to see why this is true(probably due to my not so sound linear algebra background).

Can anyone help me in understanding why the argument is true? Thanks.

Link to paper: https://www.cs.tau.ac.il/~shpilka/publications/RazShpilka_PIT.pdf

Comment: A spanning set can be reduced to a basis, so the dimension is less than or equal to the number of vectors you started out with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $\Bbb F$ be the underlying field. A vector with $k$ components is a vector in $\Bbb F^k$, which is a vector space of dimension $k$. If $V$ is the span of $n$ vectors in $\Bbb F^k$, then it is a subspace of $\Bbb F^k$: in particular, its dimension is less or equal to the dimension of $\Bbb F^k$, that is, $k$.

Comment: Got it. Thank you!

Comment: Hi @Isaac, would you help me understand "dimension is less to the dimension of $\mathbb{F}^k$"? Also wouldn't $\begin{Bmatrix} (1, 0, 0) & (0, 1, 0) \end{Bmatrix}$ span 2d space despite being $\mathbb{R}^3$ vector?

Comment: I have read https://mathworld.wolfram.com/VectorBasis.html before reading your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Denote the $n$ vectors by $v_1, \cdots, v_n \in W$ (where $W$ is the vector space you're working with). To say that each vector has $k$ components is the same as saying that $W$ is $k$-dimensional, that is, that there exist $k$ linearly independent vectors $e_1, \cdots, e_k$ such that their span is equal to $W$ and that no combination of less than $k$ vectors can possibly span $W$ (and of course, also that any combination of more than $k$ vectors is linearly dependent). So the result you want follows by the very definition of dimension and basis.

Comment: "$W$ is k-dimensional", is it ok to called it same as dimension of vector? If yes, are you asserting that dimension (number of components) of vector will **always** be same as number of linearly dependent vectors in the subspace used to span the vector space $W$ (aka basis vectors). [ref](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/VectorBasis.html)